# change Formsauthentication settings for a specific user or role

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

as the website doesn't use SSL , I have set the slidingExpiration to false . but I want it to be true for admin user ( role ) . is there any way to set it true setting for one user ( role ) and false for normal users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ticket is generated manually by using the FormsAuthenticationTicket class, the time-out can be set through the Expiration attribute. This value will override the timeout attribute value specified in configuration files. So when your Admin user signs in you can use this to manually set the expiration characteristics for that user based on their role.